# Last line of text cut off when extracting text from PDF using MuPDF

Tags: ios, pdf, text-extraction, mupdf

I'm using MuPDF to extract some text from a pdf file. Most of the time it works fine, but occasionally the last line will either not extract or not print.

```
fz_text_sheet *sheet = fz_new_text_sheet(self.ctx);
fz_text_page *text = fz_new_text_page(self.ctx, &fz_empty_rect);
fz_device *dev = fz_new_text_device(self.ctx, sheet, text);

fz_page *page = fz_load_page(self.doc, pageNumber);
fz_run_page(self.doc, page, dev, &fz_identity, NULL);

fz_output *out = fz_new_output_file(ctx, stdout);
fz_print_text_page_html(ctx, out, text);
```

The first page of this [PDF](http://support.fastpdfkit.com/discussions/problems/489/assets/9633b40eb441c68ca86c1785c1b9ddee22cbc8b4/50_Best_Videos_for_Kids.pdf?anon_token=) fails to print the last line of text on that page.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to free the text device before you can use the fz_text_page safely. There may be some stuff buffered in the device that doesn't get flushed until it's freed.

Comment: Life saver! Indeed fz_free_device(dev) solves the problem